Camera Index out of range when trying to use cv2.VideoCapture(0) for the second time
(On Raspberry Pi 5) I am using a python script (control.py) to start another python script (main.py) in a separate thread. main.py uses cv2 to get frames from a webcam attached to my Raspberry Pi. control.py has an interval mode, meaning it starts main.py, which executes until a fixed time is reached, pauses, and then starts main.py again. The first time, everything works flawlessly. However, the second time, I get this error:

[ERROR:1388@32.582] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:158 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range
[ WARN:1389@32.583] global cap_v4l.cpp:999 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index

I am calling cap.release() and cv2.destroyAllWindows() when exiting main.py.
I figured the issue might be that cap.release() is not working as expected. But if the resource is still busy, the error should be "Device or resource busy", according to this question.

USB webcam, other USB camera/video device, or some kind of "pi camera" attached with a flatflex ribbon cable? [mre] required. [tour], [ask]. processes aren't threads. you can't start another script in another thread, only as another process. usually you can't access the same video device from multiple processes/threads concurrently.

we can't run code, we can't even see it, and we can't read in your mind - so don't expect answer. You have to show all details in question (not in comments)
